# What is the latest, tested, Ubuntu version which works on a MacBook 1,1 (early 2006)

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, macbook

Which version of Lubuntu can I install on a MacBook 1,1 (early 2006, Intel Dual Core with 2 GB of RAM)? Or should I go for an earlier Ubuntu, or Kubuntu? I would prefer an older version than the latest one if this brings stability and speed.

Thanks,

Val

Comment: There are only two supported Lubuntu versions available, 14-04 and 14.10 so you are limited there.  All other versions of Lubuntu have reached their End of Life.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop's specs are similar to yours but I have more RAM. I have no problems with lubuntu 14.04

Even when I first got my computer 5 years ago I found the kubuntu at the time was a bit slow on it. I don't think that's an option. KDE (kubuntu) and Unity (ubuntu default) are designed to be fancy and beautiful, not lightweight.

Ubuntu with gnome or Xubuntu would be other options, but personally I like lubuntu best, and it's the lightest.

If you want something even lighter than lubuntu there is puppy linux http://puppylinux.org/wikka/tahrpup

I don't think it's necessary to go that light.